# Java - Traversing an Array Node

Tags: java, jackson

I am attempting to traverse the following JSON text below.  The problem is I am not sure how to retrieve the coordinates array from the coordinates path in Java. in the following format lon/lat.  I have included a JSON string that I am attempting to parse, however I am not sure how to traverse into the array with Jackson Functions.

Coordinates

```
"coordinates": {
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [-82.3248262, 29.6516344]
```

Java Code

```
if(root.path("coordinates").path("coordinates").isArray() && 
   root.path("coordinates").path("coordinates") != null) {
        lat = root.path("coordinates").path("coordinates").get(1).asText();
        lon = root.path("coordinates").path("coordinates").get(0).asText();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The json you provided here does not parse.

This would be correct:

```
{
  "coordinates": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [
      -82.3248262,
      29.6516344
    ]
  }
}
```

Or a flattened version:

`{"coordinates":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-82.3248262,29.6516344]}}`

Once you have the code parse that string to a json node, your provided if-statement works fine.

EDIT: As Avi mentions in the comments, .path() returns a MissingNode instance, not null. If you want to check for null, do a .get(). Or you could just use .has() which will return true or false.

Comment: my apologies forgot to copy and paste the entire JSON string.  You are correct its working now.

Comment: @user2100493 the `if` statement that checks for `null` would never be true in case the path does not exists, because `path()` method returns `MissingNode` object and not null.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you have critical error in your `if` condition:

According to `Jackson` library, the method `path()` returns `MissingNode` object instead of `null` when the path is not found, and therefore you need to fix your `if` condition accordingly.

Because `MissingNode` is type of `Jackson` datatype, the check for the `MissingNode` is redundent, and you can just check if its an `ArrayNode`.

> [path(String fieldName)](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html#path(java.lang.String))
>
> This method is similar to get(String), except
>   that instead of returning null if no such value exists (due to this
>   node not being an object, or object not having value for the specified
>   field), a "missing node" (node that returns true for isMissingNode())
>   will be returned.

Second, to iterate the `ArrayNode` you can do this:

```
if (root.path("coordinates").path("coordinates").isArray()) {
  lat = root.path("coordinates").path("coordinates").get(1).asText();
  lon = root.path("coordinates").path("coordinates").get(0).asText();
}
```